# Is creating a single input component that changes its type based on props and supports all input types feasible? Or would the component become complex

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and decided to try creating a form with different inputs. After copy-pasting the labels and inputs for all different input types 10 times, I felt like I should try to create a component that would render different inputs based on the props passed to it.

I created the following component that works fine for inputs like text, password, email, number. I use it like this:

```
<FormGroup
    inputType="text"
    inputName="firstName"
    inputPlaceholder="First Name"
</FormGroup>
```

And here's the component:

```
const FormGroup = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="form-label" htmlFor={props.inputName}>
                <p>{props.inputPlaceholder}</p>
            </label>
            <input
                type={props.inputType}
                name={props.inputName}
                placeholder={props.inputPlaceholder}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default FormGroup;
```

The problem is that as soon as I started thinking about inputs like upload, range, checkbox, date, range, I started wondering if creating a universal input component that can handle any input type feasible. Maybe the component will become too big/complex/confusing. Should I continue trying to create such universal input component, or try an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could.
No, you (probably) shouldn't.

Technically, there is no limitation in putting this together, and for input that is quite similar (text input, date input, number input) its actually probably a nice thing to have.

However, when you jump across to an element like `<select>` where its props are quite different, it will not only make the internals of your component more complex, but the components consuming your universal component more complex too, which imo, is a much more important consideration.

I typically have the following components in most typical web projects:

- `<Input />` (supports text, number and date)
- `<Select />`
- `<Checkbox />` and `<Checkboxes />` as a wrapper
- `<Radio />` and `<Radios />` as a wrapper
- `<Upload />` - its own beast

Answer (score 1):

It is doable but it become very complex as you add support to more types.

For form handling you'd better use a library that also manages the state of your inputs.

Formik is a popular and solid choice at the moment
https://formik.org/

Try to go through their docs, even if you decide not to use it, it should give you a better understanding of the requirements for what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

There is a principle in programming called [singled-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) that'll help you better structure your code. Keep things simple! The first problem I see is that your component is doing multiple things. It does display a form group which is about grouping elements together (**children**), like a label and a form element. But it goes on displaying also the actual label and an input (what about other types of form element?). It should have just been **a wrapper**.

An `<input>` already accepts different types of input. But a FormGroup can not only accept an input but other things, too, like select and what not. So you'll then add more complexity to your component.

Javascript is great, it's permissive, you can do all sort of things. Imageine at some point, you'll decide to add Typescript to your project. Or better yet, you'll want to write tests for your component. How are you going to test such a monster component. Grouping things like that is great, it saves you some time for a while but at some point, you'll want to have the liberty to add whatever you want as children. As it is now, you'll have to modify your component each time you want to add something different under your component. Again, it should have just been **a wrapper**.

And lastly, in general, when you add if's to your component (you'll have to at some point and if I understand correctly where you're going) which is a signal that your component has **many behaviors** which goes against the single-responsibility principle, ask yourself if it would not be better to separate this into two or more components. I've seen codes where there was a component that would take a boolean and would either render this or that jsx whether we would pass true or false. And the props that we pass in each situation would also be different. This is a good candidate for refactoring...

Oh, one other last thing to note. You probably want to use [reactsrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) (assuming you're using bootstrap that is). It has a FormGroup and anything else. You won't have to create these components yourself.

---

Use children or props?

Sometimes, you probably wonder why you have to bother passing children each time, especially when it's the same code over and over again. That goes against DRY... and that's what you wanted to avoid. But you lose control over the children. If you want to add some classes to the inputs, to the label or whatever else, you'll also have to pass these by props, too... labelClasses, inputClasses.

Let's take an example, an [antd table](https://ant.design/components/table/):

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
    key: 'age',
  },
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'address',
    key: 'address',
  },
];

<Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />;
```

Okay, this is great. I won't have to repeat the columns myself. But what you can do with these columns are somewhat limited.

Whereas, with this:

```
<Table dataSource={dataSource}>
  <Column></Column>
</Table>
```

I can take the Column and wrap it into a [styled-component](https://styled-components.com/):

```
const MyStyledColumn = styled(Column)``

<Table dataSource={dataSource}>
  <MyStyledColumn></MyStyledColumn>
</Table>
```

Pretty cool.